# Codewarrior won't open .mcp project file

Tags: codewarrior

A colleague of mine has been working on a project in Codewarrior and I have come on board to assist.

When trying to open the .mcp project file that she has created (and is working fine on her codewarrior) I get the following error.

[image: error1]

Similarly - when I try to open her workspace file, I get the following error.

[image: error2]

Important to note, we are using the exact same versions of codewarrior and I am able to open and work with other codewarrior projects.

Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be caused by SVN interpreting this as a non-binary file. Problem was solved by exporting her codewarrior project to an XML file and then importing this to my machine, creating my own .mcp file.

Simple really - just putting an answer up in-case someone googles across this again.